# Installing Steam games on laptop to move later to Windows PC

Tags: windows, games, steam

So I have Ubuntu on my Laptop and a Windows desktop PC which I use mostly for gaming. The problem is I have a really crap internet connection at home so I wanted to install my games on my Laptop (at my friend's house for ex.) and move them to my PC later. But, on Steam I can only install games that are available on Linux, obv, and there is no option, that I could find, to install the games for windows. So, is there a way to install Steam's games for windows on Ubuntu, but not to play them just download them?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Proton/Steam Play to install the Windows binaries of your games on the Linux system, then copy the install directories with the binaries to your Windows machine.

To install any Windows game on Linux, go to Steam settings in the category "Steam Play" and check "Enable Steam Play for supported titles" and "Enable Steam Play for all other titles".

In order to force installing the Windows binaries even though there is a Linux version of a game, right-click on the game in question, open "Properties", and on the bottom of the "General" tab, check "Force the use of a specific Steam Play compatibility tool" and select one of the Proton versions. It doesn't matter which one since you won't use it anyway.

If you copy the files into a proper Steam library on Windows, it should recognize them.